# how to create my own formula with specific variable

Tags: r, string, function

I have a dataset with 4 columns and want to apply my own formula for the dataset with specific column condition

the dataset is

```
s.no  id  sex  age  cre
1   103469  M   68  0.9
2   103469  M   68  NULL
3   103469  F   68  NULL
4   103469  F    68 0.8
5   103469  M   68  0.8
6   103469  M   69  0.9
```

the formula i want to construct would be `A*(cre/B)^C*0.993^age)`

where

```
A = 150
B = 20
C = 29
```

I want to apply this formula if column sex = "M" and cre <0.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can use `transform` with `ifelse` assuming `df` is the dataframe name

```
transform(df,new_form = ifelse(sex == "M" & cre < 0.9, A*(cre/B)^C*0.993^age, NA))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[sex == "M" & cre < 0.9, formula := A*(cre/B)^C*0.993^age]
```

Comment: thanks for the code its work perfectly in male. For female group i used  
`transform(e,new_form_2 = ifelse(sex == "F" & cre > 0.7, 144*(cre/0.7)^-1.209*0.993^age, NA))` ... once this done it results correct values for female and hidden the male value. . suggest me the code for impelmenting two conditions in the same time.

Comment: @king_arrival27 Combine both the conditions in `case_when` or use nested `ifelse`, `transform(df,new_form = ifelse(sex == "M" & cre < 0.9, A*(cre/B)^C*0.993^age, 
                               ifelse(sex == "F" & cre > 0.7, 144*(cre/0.7)^-1.209*0.993^age, NA)))
`

Comment: the exact output I needed and perfectly dude thanks for your work and support it is working accurately.